# How can i fix the dispose object error in static methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How can i get a list with all the data and reference data from database  from a static function? I try to use `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;` but the function return only the project info and the reference data was null.

```cs
public static Project GetProject(Guid ProjectID)
        {
            if (!ProjectID.Equals(null))
            {
                using (var db = new dbEntity())
                {
                    return db.Projects.Single(Project => Project.Id.Equals(ProjectID));

                }

            }
            return null;
        }
```

Error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

Where i call the function:

```
@{var project = StaticMethods.GetProject(Guid.Parse(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString()));}
@for(var item in project.Users().ToList()){
 ....
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of `Project`

Comment: @MichaelRandall its a auto-generated model from db  ``` public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; } public virtual ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; } ```

Comment: Also, `if (ProjectID.Equals(null))` is going to throw a NullReferenceException if `ProjectID` is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq eager loading and express explicitly what do you want to include to resulting objectgraph. Eager loading is achieved with [`.Include()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)-method.

You did not provide model classes of your entities, but I assume that relationship is one-one (Project has Reference as property). Following snippet loads `Project` with it's `Reference`-property:

```
public static Project GetProject(Guid ProjectID)
{
    if (!ProjectID.Equals(null))
    {
        using (var db = new dbEntity())
        {
            return db.Projects.Include(r => r.Reference).Single(Project => Project.Id.Equals(ProjectID));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, lazy loading **is** the problem.

It's caused by the following:

1. You open the *DbContext*
2. Perform your *query*
3. *Return* your `Project`
4. Access a *virtual* property which is trying to lazily load a related resources after the *DbContext* is disposed.

You will have to do one of the following:

- Turn lazy loading off.
- [Include / Eager load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) any related resources `Project` uses.